# Android sdk manager not working in visual studio 2022 for mac monterey

Tags: android-sdk-manager, macos-monterey, visual-studio-mac-2022

I'm becoming crazy...
I tried three times to reinstall Monterey and Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise for Mac.

Fresh install of Monterey last version at today on mac intel (12.4).
Install of visual studio 2022 enterprise for mac last version at today (17.0.1 build 72).
Android SDK Manager does not work.

How to reproduce the problem:

1. Open Android sdk manager (Tools > Android Sdk Manager).
2. Click on Android 9.0 - Pie check box to install Android SDK Platform28 (as an example)
3. Click on "Apply Changes" pushbutton.
4. "Apply Changes" becomes disabled for a moment but nothing happens.
5. "Apply Changes" becomes enabled, click on it another time.
6. Android 9.0 - Pie check box becomes unchecked and nothing happens,
   sometimes a crash is recorded to be sent to Microsoft.

Android SDK Location and Java SDK Location are ok.

I cannot use "Report a Problem because it does not work.
I can open "Report a Problem" but if i click on "Report a New Problem" button nothing happens and sometimes Visual Studio crashes.

Please, help me.

Comment: No way to resolve the problem and Microsoft did not found a solution... i will try when Visual Studio 2022 for Mac version 17.4 will be released

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem.  I worked around it, by using the SDK Command Prompt in Visual Studio 2022 (Tools->SDK Command Prompt).  I have version 17.0.2 (build 8) Community Version.
Once in the terminal, change into cmdline-tools/[version]/bin.
You can then list available packages:

```
./sdkmanager --list
```

You can install various packages:

```
./sdkmanager --install "system-images;android-26;default;x86"
./sdkmanager --install "platforms;android-26"
```

Restart Visual Studio to see the changes applied.  I was then able to create a device for testing.

Comment: Hi John, thank you for your answer.
I know i can use sdkmanager command line directly but, as you said, it is a workaround.
I've opened an incident with Microsoft that is working on it and i will update this post as soon as i have news.

Comment: @StefanoZambonin, do you have an update on this? Would you mind sharing a link to the Microsoft incident? Thanks.